# PHP Mailer 'PHP Parse error'

Tags: php, phpmailer

Ao usar o PHP Mailer ele esté me retornando a seguinte mensagem

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in plugins\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php on
>   line 288

Meu código conforme abaixo

```
require 'plugins/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'plugins/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'plugins/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';

$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From      = 'teste@teste.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Seu nome';
$email->Subject   = 'Assunto';
$email->Body      = 'Teste';
$email->AddAddress( 'teste@teste.com' );

$file_to_attach = 'teste';
$email->AddAttachment( $file_to_attach , 'teste.pdf' );

$email->Send();
```

Fiz Download na https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Qual motivo do erro ?

Comment: O motivo é que você está utilizando uma versão obsoleta do PHP. Você precisa alterar a versão do seu PHP para 5.4 ou superior.

Comment: Obrigado era isso mesmo, mas quando executa aparece erro 500